# Host Web Application in IIS ONLY for users logged into the hosting machine

Tags: asp.net, security, iis

We have developed a web application to display *sensitive* information over our company's intranet.  We had initially planned to implement sufficient security to allow remote access via the intranet to the application through a browser.  But, due to an unforeseen requirements from our security team, we have decided not to allow remote access.  We would still like a small number of users to be able to access the application, so here's the question.  How can you host a web application in IIS visible only to users logged into the hosting machine?  (The machine is both the host of the web app, and the only machine where the web app would be visible.)

I'm relatively new to IIS, so please speak as plainly as possible.

It seems like their must exist some setting in IIS to limit incoming and outgoing requests to the current machine.

Comment: Users would have to log onto the system via remote desktop or similar system.

Comment: Correct.  But, how would we limit IIS to only display the page to users logged in through remote desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to block all IP addresses with the following:

[image]

Which can be found in IIS 7 at this location:

[image]